# How to access certain one class from multiple classes in JS on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I have a certain doubt on how to access one element from multiple class names in JavaScript. For example, here is my code.

```
<html>
<head><title>Check</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div"><button type ="submit">a</button></div>
<div class="div"><button type ="submit">b</button></div>
<div class="div"><button type ="submit">c</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button of b, then I want the second div class to be selected. Can anyone help me in this question? I am completely struck at this one problem.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is always the same, you can just use [`Node.parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) to get there, starting with a reference to the `<button>`:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return;
  
  console.log(target.parentElement.outerHTML);  
});
```

```html
<div class="div"><button type ="submit">a</button></div>
<div class="div"><button type ="submit">b</button></div>
<div class="div"><button type ="submit">c</button></div>
```

Alternatively, if the structure might be different for the different buttons, you need something like jQuery's [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). You can implement something like that using a loop or a recursive function and [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) if you are not using jQuery:

```js
function closest(element, selector) {  
  if (!element || element === document) return null;
  
  if (element.matches(selector)) return element;
  
  return closest(element.parentElement, selector);
}

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') return;
  
  console.log(closest(target, '.div').outerHTML);  
});
```

```html
<div class="div"><button type ="submit">a</button></div>
<div class="div"><span><button type ="submit">b</button></span></div>
<div class="div"><span><span><button type ="submit">c</button></span></span></div>
```